# I am not sure about the meaning of: "I went and came with Lorin’s."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am not sure about the meaning of "with Lorin’s" in the two entries below written by Bishop Milton Wright, the father of Orville and Wilbur Wright, in his diary.

What I know is that Lorin was an elder brother of the two inventors. He was married, lived in Dayton, had children and possible a car.

> • Monday, May 23, 1904
>
> It rained early in the morning.  Went out to
> Simm’s Station to see the brothers attempt to fly. Too little wind.
> Went and came **with Lorin’s**. Encountered rain on our return.
>
> • Wednesday, May 25, 1904
>
> At 2:30, we were at Huffman’s farm at Simm’s
> station to see an aëronautical flight, but a rain came up & hindered.
> Many were disappointed. I went and came **with Lorin’s**.

What did he mean by "Lorin's"? The members of his family? By car with Lorin Wright as a driver (it is unlikely he drove a primitive automobile of 1904 at the age of over 75)?

[image: The entries of May 22-25 as they appear in Bishop Milton Wright's diary]
The entries of May 23-25 as they appear in Bishop Milton Wright's diary

Comment: It's an unedited piece of dairy with many mistakes (things like [unreadable], missing words and incorrect spelling of some words). In the document I manage to find, the entry on Wednesday, May 25 says "I went and came with Lorin." (no possessive)

Comment: He wrote "Called at Lorin's" a lot, which apparently refers to the place where Lorin lived. "Went and came with Lorin’s" could mean he visited the station with the Lorin family/Loren himself/one of the Lorin family members, but it's rather ungrammatical

Comment: I added the scanned copy of the handwritten original M. Wright's diary, entries of May 22-25, 1904.

Answer (score 1):

Diaries are usually only written to be read by the author. So things context like his is often missing.  It would (probably) have been obvious to Milton Wright what he meant. Even though it is non-standard, with subjectless and verbless sentences etc.

It most likely means "Lorin's family" or "Lorin and his wife" or perhaps "Lorin and his car"

Generally such texts are not good sources for learning English.